# How can r show me the mode and how often the mode appears?

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing votes as columns and parliamentarians as rows. I want to compute an agreement index and therefore need the frequency of the mode.

A column looks e.g. like this

```
V1
1
3
2
1
1
2
1
```

I know the following code to show me the mode

```
getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

And I know how I R shows me the frequency of values

```
a <- table(df$V1)
print(a)
```

Is there a way that R takes the mode, in my example 1, and shows me how frequent it is, in my example 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
a <- table(df$V1)
max(a)
```

Or using your `getmode` function

```
sum(df$V1 == getmode(df$V1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate your `getmode()` function in this way:

```
getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  mode <- uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
  freq <- sum(v==mode)                      # here you count the values = to mode
  dats <- data.frame(                       # you can put in a data.frame
                      mode = (mode),        # mode
                      freq = (freq)         # frequency
                     )
  print(dats)                               # here you print the result               
  }

# let's try it
getmode(V1)
  mode freq
1    1    4
```

---

With data:

```
V1 <- c(1,3,2,1,1,2,1)
```